# Press key to break a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, keypress, break

C# windows form has problem that when a loop is executed, it disables all other events. So when a loop is too long, I can't stop the program properly (can't press the close button). Anyone know how to solve this problem, please help.
To simplify the problem, here is a sample code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            CheckLoop();
        }
    }

    void CheckLoop()
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 9999999;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        while (progressBar1.Value != progressBar1.Maximum)
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)//Did not break when press Alt???
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The question is how to make the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key works the way it supposes to work?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Busy wait always causing *application freezes* (search term) behavior... There are many ways to deal with it depending on what you actually doing... Searching for existing questions about "WinFrom application freezes during long operations" could give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this my friend:

```
    void CheckLoop()
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 9999999;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        while (progressBar1.Value != progressBar1.Maximum)
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)//it should stop now
                break;
        }
    }
```

`Application.DoEvents()` works if you want a quick solution.

Edit:

Depending on what you're doing you might have different needs. I consider the `timer` to be really easy to use as well.

Let's see your code using a `timer`:

## Prerequisites :

1-Add a timer component from the toolbox
  2-Double click the added timer to quickly access its `Tick` event handler.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            UpdateProgress.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do some work
        if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum) 
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
        }


        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
        {
            UpdateProgress.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried and true approach that would give you results. Best part is it pretty much guarantees re-entrancy somewhere your in event handlers and will give long and productive debugging sessions (opposed to embracing the fact that you need to handle events all the time and avoid use of busy loops in favor of events based code like timers).

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. Application.DoEvents() is what I'm looking for :)
But how about better solution?
Thank again friend, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @123iamking I updated the answer and included an example using timers. Let me know what you think. Best regards !

Comment: @earthb0und Thank you very much, you're the best :) One more question: How can I  make it stop with non-ModifierKeys, like 'Q','E',... ? Thank again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to handle it is with [Async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx), you can start the method of running the loop. Then have another key handler to stop the method.

I didn't know about the DoEvents method. I think that will be a quick and easy way to do it, actually.